# Why am I getting 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes' after reshaping?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, regression

I am very confused about this. I am trying to perform linear regression on a dataset, and I received a Value Error early in the program due to my dataset needing to be 2D instead of 1D, so I reshaped every part of my dataset like so:

```
x1_train = np.array(x1_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = np.array(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
x1_test = np.array(x1_test.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = np.array(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
x1_pred = np.array(x1_pred.reshape(-1, 1))
y_pred = np.array(y_pred.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Now, later on when I am trying to plot the training dataset, I am getting another Value Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-6b2e11318dc3> in <module>
      1 # Visualizing our results
      2 plt.scatter(x1_train, y_train, color = 'green')
----> 3 plt.plot(x1_train, y_pred, color = 'red')
      4 plt.title('Happiness Index Score vs. GDP Per Capita(Training Dataset)')
      5 plt.xlabel('GDP Per Capita')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2759 @docstring.copy(Axes.plot)
   2760 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2761     return gca().plot(
   2762         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
   2763         is not None else {}), **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1645         """
   1646         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1647         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1648         for line in lines:
   1649             self.add_line(line)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    214                 this += args[0],
    215                 args = args[1:]
--> 216             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    217 
    218     def get_next_color(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    340 
    341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (104, 1) and (52, 1)
```

Here is the code that is producing that error message/traceback:

```
plt.scatter(x1_train, y_train, color = 'green')
plt.plot(x1_train, y_pred, color = 'red')
plt.title('Happiness Index Score vs. GDP Per Capita(Training Dataset)')
plt.xlabel('GDP Per Capita')
plt.ylabel('Happiness Index Score')
plt.show()
```

Anyone understand what's going on here?

Comment: what about using .reshape(-1)? does it work?

Comment: That did not work. I also tried .reshape(1, -1) and got this error: ` ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 104 is different from 52)`

Comment: Try `x_train.reshape((-1,2))` and `y_train.reshape((-1,1))`

Comment: Got another error. `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [52, 104]`

Comment: Can you show a "short version" of `x1_train` and `y_train` (before reshaping)?

Comment: With the original code I wrote: `[[0.694]
 [0.685]
 [1.294]
...
 [1.333]
 [0.987]
 [0.   ]]
[[6.60289019]
 [4.01976756]
 [5.72381705]
...
 [3.53740435]
 [3.43146476]
 [5.47136527]]`

Comment: Is it possible that I need to round y_pred?

Comment: How do you expect to plot 52 points against 104?  Do you understand why your arrays have those shapes?  Do you understand why sizes must match?  What's the puzzle?